# The servlet does not allow to open form-login-page

Tags: java, url, servlets, weblogic, web.xml

I have servlet with 
`@WebServlet({"/*", "/secure/*"})`
annotation. The second url was created for content that can be obtained by authenticated users. And the first url for all users.

As a server I'm using weblogic. So this is my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
</security-role>
```

and weblogic.xml

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
    <principal-name>auth_user</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

So when I'm trying to request `localhost:7001/myservlet/secure?id=329`, I get `localhost:7001/myservlet/login.html`. And It is right. But I don't get my `login.html` form. My servlet thinks that this url for him and tries to process it. And I get error. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

P.S. When I remove `"/*"` from `@WebServlet` I get my `login.html` form successfully. But I can not change servlet's urls.

**UPDATE**

I deleted extra code and got this servlet code

```
@WebServlet({"/*", "/secure/*"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ContentGetter getter = new ContentGetter();

        try (OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                InputStream is = getter.getIsFromDB(request.getParameterMap())) {

            IOUtils.copy(is, os);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Object getting is failed. " + e.toString(), e);
            return;
        }
    }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
}
```

Method getter.getIsFromDB(request.getParameterMap() throws IllegalArgumentException if parameters Map is empty. An finally I get error 500.

Comment: @Rinat how can it help me?

Comment: You can use Filters to change the urls?

Comment: @Jonathan it would be better if you solve this problem without changing the servlet code. Maximum WebServlet annotation and config files. But if there are no other ideas, Filters can be used.

Comment: The problem is that you're mapping all urls to this single servlet. Normally filters are used for this kind of thing. I don't really know what you're trying to achieve specifically with this, add your servlet code so we can see better what you are trying to do

Comment: @Jonathan updated. I thought, Is it possible to place the form somewhere and refer there as an external link, and not keep it inside the project? Or somehow make their url's not intersect

Comment: Yes it's possible. Where is the RequestDispatcher? How is that servlet forwarding to the html page?

Comment: @Jonathan This servlet has no UI. It provides content on system requests. And redirection to login.html is done using web.xml (<url-pattern>/secure/*</ url-pattern>)

Comment: Servlet doesn't need a UI but you should be using them to redirect users to the appropriate place. You get a blank page correct? What error are you getting specifically. Please include it in your post

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, I have error 500. I can delete IllegalArgumentException and there will be blank page, you are right.